# PUBMED author/article database

Tags: bioinformatics, pubmed

I am looking for a way to download the  author and associated articles database from pubmed or any other source. I can't seem to locate this anywhere on ncbi FTP site.

Does anyone know if there's such database available?

Comment: Not a programming question...

Comment: If I were you I would try http://biostar.stackexchange.com.

Comment: There are several answers to this question on SO although if a particular language were specified, they would probably be duplicates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try this :

ftp://ftp.ncbi.nih.gov/pubmed/

Also, I would try the E-utilities

http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK25500/

Good luck!